# In call kit recieve incoming call not start

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

If the app is in the background and the device is locked, then after receiving the call, the call does not start. But when the app is killed and the device is locked, then after receiving the call, the call starts.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: It depends on your code. How you implemented it and what you are doing in different state of your app.

Comment: No i have not doing anything state of application.